# Embedding a beamer presentation in a regular document with RMarkdown

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, beamer

My aim is write a document in `markdown` (`rmarkdown`, more specifically), that can be compiled both to a regular PDF (or other) file *and* a beamer presentation at the same time, from the same source. (Using `knitr`.) Scenario: the document includes, in addition to the regular text, one sentence summaries for each paragraph and these should go to the presentation as the bullet points.

I know that [I can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078572/specifying-multiple-simultaneous-output-formats-in-knitr) compile a document to several different output formats at the same time with `knitr`, but the problem here is something else: the content of the document. How to include those sentences...? I must mark them somehow, and achieve that they're *not* compiled into the regular PDF, *and* at the same time *only they* should be compiled into the beamer presentation!

What's the solution here?

(I'm planning to do this with `bookdown`, but I have the feeling that it doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `beamerarticle` package to build an article class document from the beamer sources. I couldn't convince rmarkdown to build both documents at the same time, but the following works with alternating the header between the lines for the beamer output and the article document and renaming the output file in between:

````
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
#  pdf_document: 
#    includes:
#      in_header: preamble.tex
---

sentence in both documents

``` {=latex}
\only<article>{
  sentence only in the article
}
```

``` {=latex}
\only<presentation>{
  sentence only in the presentation
}
```
````

With `preamble.tex`:

```
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
```

Complete rstudio project: https://rstudio.cloud/project/725309

Comment: Thank you @samcarter ! In the meantime I also developed a solution. It has its own problems, but I believe it is better than this, at least in terms of automatization. (But I'd really love to hear your opinion!)

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to put together an approach which is working - I believe - perfectly, although it has some not-really-elegant solutions, and therefore there is very likely (a lot of) room for improvement.

The basic idea is to include margin notes, both in HTML and PDF, and then these margin notes are those that will be displayed in the presentation. So they serve two purpose: a quick summary of the paragraph (somewhat Tufte-style) and the basis for creating the presentation.

The presentation comes only in one format, there is no incremental version, where bullet points appear one-by-one. (Actually, there are no more bullet points at all, texts are simply displayed as sentences in different paragraphs.)

To achieve this, I used the [custom block](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/custom-blocks.html) function of `bookdown`:

````
    Text

    ```{block, type="handout"}
    Margin note
    ```

    Text
````

Here are the details:

- When compiling to HTML, the custom block conveniently compiles into a `div`, with appropriate `type`, so all we have to do is the format it in the CSS file:

```
p {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 20%;
}
li:not(.chapter) {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 20%;
}
.handout {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  width: 18%;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
}
.handout p {
  font-size:100%;
  line-height:1.3;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

- When compiling into PDF, we unfortunately get an environment, but we can use the `environ` package to turn it to a single - `marginnote` - command:

```
\NewEnviron{handout}{\marginnote{\footnotesize \BODY}[0.23cm]}
```

- When compiling to `beamer`, things get a bit trickier. I found a similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864859/producing-markdown-slides-and-article-with-the-same-source) which uses preprocessor. Instead of that, I've chosen to use Pandoc's filters. Luckily, we even have an [example](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#creating-a-handout-from-a-paper) that is quite close to what we want! We will use a lua filter, however, a few things should be tuned...
- First, `documentclass` is set "globally" (in `index.Rmd`) to `book` which won't work with beamer. Thus, in both beamer formats, we have to reset it:

```
function Meta(m)
  if FORMAT=="beamer" then m.documentclass="beamer" end
  return m
end
```

- Next, we should crop out everything, except the marginnotes and the figures. The former is recognized by looking for `RawBlock` type with `tex` format which contains the text `handout`, the latter needs some tweaking. Albeit it is a completely unrelated issue, here are the details: the part of the filter that recognizes the Image part should also be [modified](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5911) to work with Rmarkdown generated files: `(el.t == "Para" and el.c[1].t == "Image") or`. More importantly, even this won't work if we use `fig.align` or something like that as it changes the generated markdown's format from `![]()` to direct LaTeX code. So we have to add another condition: `(el.t == "RawBlock" and el.format == "tex" and string.match( el.text, "includegraphics" ) ) or`. Overall, here is the second part of the lua filter:

```
function Pandoc(doc)
    if FORMAT=="beamer" then
      local hblocks = {}
      for i,el in pairs(doc.blocks) do
          if (el.t == "Div" and el.classes[1] == "handout") or
             (el.t == "BlockQuote") or
             (el.t == "RawBlock" and el.format == "tex" and string.match( el.text, "includegraphics" ) ) or
             (el.t == "RawBlock" and el.format == "tex" and string.match( el.text, "handout" ) ) or
             (el.t == "OrderedList" and el.style == "Example") or
             (el.t == "Para" and el.c[1].t == "Image") or
             (el.t == "Header") then
             table.insert(hblocks, el)
          end
      end
      return pandoc.Pandoc(hblocks, doc.meta)
    end
end
```

- The fact that we don't cut out the `handout` environment means that we have to do something with it, we simply translate it to text:

```
\NewEnviron{handout}{\BODY}
```

- We still have to be careful to break long slides. Luckily, there is an `allowframebreaks` option in beamer (which is considered evil, but I think here it is completely justified, or rather, we don't have any better solution); the only problem is that we can't add it to each slide, as we have no direct control on the LaTeX code for the frames. Luckily, there's a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100472/beamer-allowframebreaks-default-option) to modify the option in header to make it default, and we can easily do it in `preamble.tex`. I combine this solution with [a more elegant](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/423) numbering scheme:

```
\let\oldframe\frame
\renewcommand\frame[1][allowframebreaks]{\oldframe[#1]}
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}{only if multiple}{%
    \ifnum \numexpr \beamer@endpageofframe+1-\beamer@startpageofframe\relax > 1
        \insertcontinuationcount.%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

- The most non-elegant part is that we can't include the `beamer_presentation` output to twice, and with different names, or at least I don't know a [solution for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010344/compiling-the-same-bookdown-project-twice-to-the-same-output-format-but-with-di) so we have to manually compile it with `bookdown::render_book` *and* don't forget to rename (and move) the resulting compiled file afterwards.
- This also means that we have to give up using the `Build Book` button, unfortunately. We rather have to create a script to do all what the button would (and I hope that I made no mistake, and it is indeed doing the same as the button...):

```
bookdown::render_book( "index.Rmd", "bookdown::pdf_book" )
bookdown::render_book( "index.Rmd", "bookdown::gitbook" )
bookdown::render_book( "index.Rmd", "bookdown::epub_book" )
bookdown::render_book( "index.Rmd", "beamer_presentation" )
file.rename( "FerenciTamas_ValszamEsStatAlapvonalai.pdf", "./docs/FerenciTamas_ValszamEsStatAlapvonalai_handout.pdf" )
```

- Finally, we also need a custom Pandoc template, as for the presentation it is easily possible that we need a short title (which is not currently supported by Pandoc). So I changed `\title{$title$$if(thanks)$\thanks{$thanks$}$endif$}` to `\title[$if(short-title)$$short-title$$endif$]{$title$$if(thanks)$\thanks{$thanks$}$endif$}` (adding a `short-title` element to `index.Rmd`).
- It's again an unrelated issue, but I also changed the `\frame{\sectionpage}` line in `\AtBeginSection` to

```
\begin{frame}{$toc-title$}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
```

which is of course mostly a matter of taste, but an objective reason is that it works in non-English languages as well (the original template would display "Section 1" even if non-English language is selected).

And that's it!

You can find everything put together, in a completely realized project here: https://github.com/tamas-ferenci/FerenciTamas_ValszamEsStatAlapvonalai.

Of course, I really welcome any feedback, criticism or suggestion on improvement.

Comment: Be careful with redefining the frame environment, this can lead to all kinds of problems. For one you loose the ability to pass overlay arguments to frames, for example to move complete frames to the handout.

Comment: Also having `allowframebreaks` as default option is kind of tricky, this will break all kinds of stuff, for example note pages. There is a reason the beamer user guide calls this option "evil".

Comment: @samcarter After thinking a lot on this, I completely revised the procedure, dropping the incremental slides. I know that `allowframebreaks` is still evil, but at least we don't have it combined with overlay specifications...

Answer (score 0):

I am very excited about this discussion, because I still do need help and support as well.  So I hope this will revive things, as I am obviously not the only one looking for such feature.

Unless I am mistaken, I provided an (elegant?) answer to your question here:  [creating accompanying slides for bookdown project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429949/creating-accompanying-slides-for-bookdown-project).
Did you get a chance to see it?  Does this not solve your question?  It seems to me that I am doing exactly what you are trying to achieve (I checked your `Github`)
I just did a quick search in `SO` with tags `beamer` `bookdown` and my post came up first... not for you?

**The solution** is the one you hint at: create a `bookdown` project with several output types.
 The one issue I did not manage to resolve is that i could not customize the book output filename (see comments following the `SO` question) - a pity - maybe a `bookdown` feature request? But YiHui Xie did not offer this as a suggestion - despite my hinting at it - you might ask again?
Then in an single click, you could get your `pdf beamer` slides, your `pdf` book, your `html` web book, your `epub` e-book - absolutely amazing, all thanks to XieYiHui.  Now - instead - i just do need TWO clicks, because when I compile the slides and the `pdf`, it (over)writes to the same file (actually, it does not!! it first writes in the root folder, but then moves it inside the /_book folder and that's when the overwrite takes place - so my thought was this should be a very easy fix for YiHui Xie, but maybe not?).

Anyway, all this worked absolutely perfect, until John McFarlane decided to change the fundamentals of how `Pandoc` works and basically killed my approach. The discussion is here: [Pandoc #4317 forces content under title slides to be included in a frame in pandoc > 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614387/pandoc-4317-forces-content-under-title-slides-to-be-included-in-a-frame-in-pand).  To allow *vertical* slides in a `pdf` output - a total nonsense imho - they are forcing all contents **ABOVE** slide level onto a slide!! John McFarlane did try to see if he could help me, but invoked the argument that they did not think about my case and now he does not want to revert... He even asked me to post my question in his email list, but there were no takers to help... :-( so bottom line, my solution still works perfect, as long as I use `pandoc < 2.7` (in `Rstudio`, just replace `pandoc` in the `bin` folder with an earlier version).

**Summary**:  2 things still needed for a perfect smooth solution:
1. [bookdown: customize the output filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639760/bookdown-customize-the-output-filename/57613745#57613745), just for convenience of one click solution
2. [Obtaining from John McFarlane that `Pandoc` either does not force content onto slides *randomly* or allows to escape that unwanted behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614387/pandoc-4317-forces-content-under-title-slides-to-be-included-in-a-frame-in-pand).  **That's crucial** for being able to use current `Pandoc` version.

Comment: Thanks @tshevrier for your comments! What I don't clearly see with your solution is how you mark those parts that should go to the slides (to separate from those that should go to all other formats). I have a custom block type for this, which goes to slides, *but* it is also handled to appear in the other formats, but in a specialized way (as a side note).

Comment: if you have MWE you want to share with me, i can send you the code back, most likely. But in a nutshell, all you have to do is use:  `r if (out_type=="beamer") "Whatever you want only on a slide"`.  In your setup chunk, you would have specified `##### CHECK COMPILATION TYPE #####
out_type <- knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")` as explained by XieYiHui. Becomes v easy to control all formats at once. Hope this helps. Feel free to accept my answer if does resolve your issue (it should! as it does for me perfectly, subject to this `pandoc` limitation, which i hope you can help with!)

Comment: I think this solution has two drawbacks compared to mine. The first is that if you check my lua script, you can see that many things get copied to beamer (block qoutes, lists with example style, figures etc.) in addition to texts. This is completely automatic, I don't have to do anything (the lua script recognizes figures, block quotes etc.). With your solution I'd have to manually place `r if ...` at every such object.

Comment: The other problem with your solution is that things after this `r if ...` will go *only* to the slide, but I often want objects to go *both* to slide and the regular output. With my solution, it is fully automatic, with yours, I'd have to duplicate every such object, which is really cumbersome and error-prone.

Comment: You are making an assumption here, I believe. You are assuming that I need that comment to put things in slides. That's not at all what I wrote. I wrote clearly "only". The way I set this up is very simple and exactly as I explained above. Let me repeat.

Comment: you create bookdown - you type your content. Things get compiled in pdf book, epub book, html book, and pdf slides. NOW IF you want content that's only slides, I gave you the technique. It also works for formatting - that's the ONLY way you can get coloring, center, italics, etc... which are not handled by bookdown natively. My code allows to have a single command compiling properly to the various versions. More importantly - everything is native bookdown style. if beamer is really ONLY for the very beamer specific content (e.g. "-" to get an item - which might not be wanted for book!)

Comment: as people always say - provide an MWE and we can all see how this works so well and so smooth. Again, just a plain vanilla bookdown project, with slides.

Comment: It might be the case that I didn't understand you clearly. I have shown how my example works in practice (with the Github repo), if you show a working example for yours, I'll happily have a look at it.

Comment: ok - let me look into this then. You will see how simple. ONE click for ALL formats (except for the pdf overwrite - i can't help that one - nor can I help the pandoc unfortunate change). I have not used my GitHub in a very long time, let's see if i can still do that...

Comment: i gave it a shot here - https://github.com/tchevri/BookdownExample. works well on my end, obviously... Let me know if any questions. Fyi - this is a very much reduced version of my textbook project, which comes with slides, etc...